# Firefox authentication window freezes background script of Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I got an private extension running, which listens to WebRequests and do stuff on specific (non-existent) URL:

```
browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    doSomething, 
    {urls: ["*://*.xx-xxxxx.net/xxx/connect?*"]}, 
    ["blocking"]
);
```

It extracts the query parameters, discards the new tab and connects to a service. Easy and well working, when Firefox is opened and running.

By clicking on the URL with Firefox closed it is only working, when there is no authentication window (e.g. proxy). If the authentication window is shown the whole background script freezes and won't progress until it is closed. 
The url is only valid for a short time, so that the freeze is holding it up too long and the url gets invalid.

Are there any possibilities to let the background script running regardless of whether the authantication window is shown or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By clicking on the URL with Firefox closed

Do you mean clicking a URL in another application that causes the Firefox to launch and open the link?

During the startup, Firefox loads the persistent listeners first. That means `browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener()` must be on top level of your background script. Is that the case?
Otherwise, it loads it later and by the time it loads, Firefox has already made several connections attempts and if they require authentication, the modal Auth pop-up comes up.

> Are there any possibilities to let the background script running
>   regardless of whether the authantication window is shown or not.

`browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener()` is fired before the Auth pop-up. 
Meanwhile, ["blocking"] will prevent further action on that request until the request is resolve.
`doSomething` must be a promise in order to prevent the execution of pop-up e.g. passing the request back to the browser to handle.

The `doSomething` then must handle the auth by allowing, blocking or redirecting etc.

The background script can run, regardless of the auth-pop but that depends on how the code is written. The auth pop-up does not stop the background script running.

Comment: doSomething() as Promise was the key. Now it works. Thank you very much.